# How to install a powershell module inside a docker container using a docker file

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, containers

I have a basic powershell script which makes changes to SharePoint online (Office365). This task requires Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell module to be installed in the system where the script is to be executed.

Below is my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest

WORKDIR ./

CMD pwsh -Command Install-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser -Force

COPY SampleScript.ps1 ./

CMD pwsh .\SampleScript.ps1
```

when I'm running:

`docker run --name "pwsh-demo" --interactive --tty dockerdemo`

I'm not able to get into interactive mode. But when I'm trying to enter the container manually and installing the module manually without using dockerfile, then the module is installing but when I'm running the script, it's throwing error saying:

```
The term 'Connect-SPOService' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
     | correct and try again.
```

Though the module is installed, I verified using the below command:

`Get-Module -ListAvailable`

[image]